# asp.net, click on buttonlink stops working in firefox after once javascript function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, firefox

The web application is based on asp.net vb, including bootstrap.
When I dismiss the Success! alert which also contains 'onclick' function call named as 'updateBadge' alert of bootstrap, all asp:Linkbutton of the page (which is in Master Page ) stops working
[This is the snap of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MRxJ.jpg)

```js
function updateBadge(tgt) {
    var cnt = document.getElementById(tgt).innerHTML;
    cnt = cnt - 1;
    document.getElementById(tgt).innerHTML = cnt.toString();
    $("#" + tgt + "_h").val(cnt.toString());
}
```

```html
<a class="my_class" href="#" id="EE55" >
    <span runat ="server"  class="badge badge-notify" id="left_push" style="background-color:red;">0</span>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="left_push_h" runat="server" value="0"/>
</a>         


<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" onclick="updateBadge('left_push')" aria-label="close">x</button>
    <strong> Success!</strong>
    Welcome user1 !! your last login was at xxxx:xxxx
</div>
```

And below are some of the link button which stops working after alert click in Firefox, working well in Microsoft Edge

```html
<li>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="settings" runat="server" ToolTip="Settings"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span></asp:LinkButton>
</li>

<li>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="configuration" runat="server" ToolTip="Configuration"><span class="fa fa-gears"></span></asp:LinkButton>
</li>

<li>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="logout" runat="server" ToolTip="Logout"><span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span></asp:LinkButton>
</li>
```

I will be grateful for any help ..

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Absolutely No error in console

Comment: Is it 'onclick' conflict with bootstrap alert dismiss ?